# The horse PAWED at the sky. Is pawed appropriate here?

Tags: single-word-requests

> "The horse PAWED at the sky."

Now, I don't think **pawed** is used appropriately here.

What word can go in its place?

I'm looking for something that can help the reader visualize a horse rearing onto its back legs with its two front legs in the air.

Any ideas for what word I can use in this instance?

Comment: The horse reared back, kicking at the sky.

Comment: I played charades with my horse-expert wife and she came up with "pawed at the air" unprompted, so I'd go with that.

Comment: @JesseM I was more looking for a single word to fill in the blank.  I plan to  say, "a horse _ at the sky" (or something similar) and then follow with something else to describe.  Do you think "kicked" would work?

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks!  If your wife said "pawed" unprompted, that's definitely a good sign! My hesitation was with not finding it in the dictionary and the fact that horses have hooves rather than paws.  But I might go with it anyway.

Comment: As someone has answered now, reared by itself seems to work. Kicked alone is unclear about which set of legs.

Comment: @Abs Google "horse pawing ground" and you will see that despite having hooves, *pawing* is widely used to describe horses acting this way.

Comment: Standard L'Amour fare: "The stallion raked the sky with both razorsharp forehooves."

Comment: JEL I like that a lot.  Beautifully written sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the slightly metaphorical ***struck at the sky***.

We seem to hesitate at **reared**, perhaps because it focuses on the wrong legs.  **Pawed** troubles some because horses don't have *paws*, but *hooves*.  **Hoofed the sky** sounds silly, because it's a verb only in a colloquial sense, meaning something else entirely.

When a horse gets up on its hind legs and takes a whack at you, you're being ***struck*** by the horse.  If you fall to the ground, you may be trampled, but that's another bale of hay entirely.

In defense of ***strike / struck*** here's a passage of immortal Wikipedia prose on the subject of "Rearing_horse"

> A horse that rears when being handled by a human who is on the ground also presents a hazard, as it is able to **strike** out with its front feet and can also fall even without the weight of a rider to unbalance the animal. A rearing horse can also break away and escape from a human handler.
>
> However, rearing also has survival value in the wild. It is a tactic that can be used to dislodge a predator that has landed on the animal's back, it is used when equids fight one another, and a horse can rear slightly to add force when **striking** out with its front feet. For these reasons, horses, particularly young ones, are sometimes seen rearing when loose in a pasture, particularly when playing or mock-fighting with pasturemates.

*Rather more than you wanted to know, eh?*

Answer (score 0):

***Rear*** is defined as "(of a horse or other animal) raise itself up on its hind legs" ([here](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+reared&sourceid=silk&ie=UTF-8)).

- The horse reared at the sky

Comment: I used "reared" in my description but I wasn't aware it could be used that way!  Interesting.  I think I'm looking for something slightly different though... "pawed at the sky" gives a slightly different visual than "reared at the sky", at least in my mind.